# Rails renders 404 page when linking to PDF file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**The problem**

I have this search function on my website, it works but for `Meetings`, and only `Meetings`, it doesn't. When I try to link to the pdf file that `Meeting` contains using `asset_path` I get the 404 page.

**This is my Meeting model**

```
    class Admin::Meeting < ApplicationRecord

        # Image/File Uploader
        mount_uploader :agenda, FileUploader
        mount_uploader :minutes, FileUploader

        has_many :meeting_translations, dependent: :destroy
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :meeting_translations

     end
```

**My file uploader looks like this, I use CarrierWave**

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # require 'RMagick'

  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # before :cache, :setup_available_sizes
  # before :cache

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  permissions 0777  
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.name.demodulize.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process resize_to_fit: [200, 200]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  def extension_whitelist
    %w(pdf doc docx xls xlsx)
  end

  def size_range
    1..10.megabytes
  end

end
```

**This is my view where I try to link to `agenda` (`agenda` is a file)**

```
<% @meeting_results.each do |result| %>
       <% unless result.agenda.nil? %>
         <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="col-sm-1"><i class="far fa-file-pdf fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
             <div class="col-sm-10">
               <div class="results-link">
                 <a href="<%= asset_path result.agenda %>"><%= result.agenda.file.original_filename %></a>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

**This is the error I get**

[404_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvfz.png)

I usually don't have this problem when I link to PDFs, I don't know if it's because I also have another file called `minutes` for `Meeting`? Anyways, any help is appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

I also noticed that the path returned from asset_path does not contain the `Meeting`s ID. This is the path it gives me`uploads/meeting/agenda/Bathurst_Regular_Public_Meeting_Agenda_May_15-2017.pdf` when the file is really located in `uploads/meeting/agenda/ID/Bathurst_Regular_Public_Meeting_Agenda_May_15-2017.pdf`

Comment: Put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a complete idiot, my query for finding the Meeting's that matched my search term was wrong.

**What I had**

`@meeting_results = Admin::Meeting.select(:agenda).where("meetings.agenda LIKE ? OR meetings.minutes LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%").distinct`

**What I replaced it with**

`@meeting_results = Admin::Meeting.where("meetings.agenda LIKE ? OR meetings.minutes LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%").distinct`

I had the wrong query due to a change I had made and decided not to go with it. Hope this maybe helps someone some day :(